# How do I deploy NServicebus Hosts from Visual Studio to my Server?

Tags: nservicebus

I'm running Visual Studio 2012 and my Server is Windows Server 2012 Essentials. I've installed MSMQ and then ran the NServicebus4 installer (the release notes says to install MSMQ first).

Everything works fine on my workstation, and I want to deploy to a server. My assumption is that all I need to do is copy everything from bin to my server, and install the host.exe as a service. That seems clunky.

Surely there is an established recommended procedure for deployement, and that someone will tell me to RTFM, except I'm not sure where the manual is. I saw that for version 3 there was an interface I could implement, but is deprecated for version 4, and version 4 has powershell commandlets, but that seems to be for preparing a server for first run. I need to install actual host services now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Installation heading in [The NServiceBus Host](http://particular.net/articles/the-nservicebus-host) in the documentation. It's a ways down the page. TL;DR: You run the same command line host with the /install parameter. There are additional options to customize. Is that what you're referring to as clunky because it's pretty straightforward as far as installing services goes.

As far as RTFM, [there is a book on the subject now](http://www.packtpub.com/build-distributed-software-systems-using-dot-net-enterprise-service-bus/book). (Disclaimer: I wrote it.)

Comment: yes, i thought there might be some other process than  - Build your project in release, copy files in bin/release to your server, run `NServiceBus.Host.exe [/install] [/serviceName]` in the mean time I'll put in a PO for the book

Comment: Do you have a vid series? I just skimmed Ch. 7 of your book (my boss processed the PO), and it doesn't actually show how to go from workstation to server for the installation processs

Comment: xcopy works just fine. Deployment topologies can be quite a bit different from how you run the system in development, so it's left open-ended. You can automate things with a deployment tool like Octopus Deploy. I've deployed fairly big systems with only a Jenkins build server and xcopy statements in batch files.